# CSSMERR_TP_NOT_TRUSTED error with Good Dynamics App Wrapping

Tags: ios, xcode5, good-dynamics

I'm trying to use [Good Dynamics App Wrapping](https://begood.good.com/blogs/product_blog/2013/06/06/app-wrapping-whats-the-big-deal) to secure my application. When I submit my app directly to the wrapping server (rather than through the Good service console), I get an error with a root cause of `CSSMERR_TP_NOT_TRUSTED`.  Any ideas for a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Mac with the Good Dynamics Wrapping Server installed on it needs Xcode installed. Unfortunately, the wrapping server documentation doesn't mention that you need to start Xcode once to complete the installation procedure. I also installed command-line tools, and created and ran a test app to enable developer mode. After doing this, app wrapping seemed to work.